# code won't compile generates infinite 2222s

Tags: c

The purpose of this code is to construct a char [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of the size of my choosing.

This question is related to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523450/c-code-constructing-a-hadamard-matrix) I asked. The answer given there was an integer not char matrix, but the code here is pretty much the same format.

The code compiles but when executed it doesn't finish and I don't know why. When executed infinite 2's are printed.

I get the same result when swap the dynamic Hadamard matrix section for one of a fixed size.

Comment: If you already asked this question but have a problem with one of your answers, comment there instead.  I'll note that you are still doing a lot more work than the answer to which you're refering ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/18523761/1832966 ).  Try collecting your three inner loops (as is done there) and using a ternary operator to do the char inversion.

Comment: Please leave the code in the question. It makes the answer look silly without it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: I've no idea what your program does, but obviously this is wrong. You failed to actually change the control variable in your for-loop (which can be done in the final expression or the loop body itself).

Change this:

```
for (ind=1;ind<=sizeH;ind*2)
```

to this:

```
for (ind=1;ind<=sizeH;ind*=2) // << note *=
```

Comment: `Hadamard.c:27:1: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]`